# how to create custom URL in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

http://example.com/siteadmin url addresses

```
<?php print $messages; ?>
<?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('admin_log')); ?>
<a href="?q=siteadmin">Admin Login</a>
```

how to set the url of the custom node in drupal 7 2
0
Drupal 7: how to create hierarchical node structure 3
0
How do you add a taxonomy field to a custom entity in Drupal 7
3
How do I save custom node types in Drupal 7 2

Answer (score 1):

your question is pretty vague. but here goes

- to create a custom url use hook_menu
- to create url alias for a custom content type you can use url alias
- For hierarchical nodes you could use or Drupal's menu system or
  Drupal's taxonomy to make such relations. Or you can also use the
  **Relation** module

What do you mean by custom entity do you mean entities defined in hook_entity_info?
or content types created through admin